# remove duplicate data in custom structure with LINQ

Tags: linq, duplicates

I want to remove duplicate data in custom structure with LINQ.

Here is my custom structure:

[image]

As you can see the yellow section consider to be duplicate data which need to remove.

First idea come into my head is using IEqualityComparer, but it seems can't work well.

If Form of A equal to To of B and To of A equal to From of B, that would be consider duplicate data.

the small From will keep, the big From will remove

For example the index 5 will keep, but the index 6 will remove.

Does anyone know how to solve this in LINQ?

Comment: Why doesn't `IEqualityComparer` seem to work well? It's the proper method for this problem.

Comment: if use IEqualityComparer , I need add a extract property in custom structure, also i need add a class

Comment: You don't need an "exact" property. You do need a class, but isn't that the idea of using an equality comparer (not sure if I understand). See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may filter your data with linq to get all the dupes and remove them afterwards.

My solution below may not be the smartest approach, but try it out.

This should conform to your custom data (it would have helped, if you would have specified it in your question):

```
public class CustomStructure
{
    public int From { get; set; }
    public int To { get; set; }
    public int Sum { get { return From + To; } }
}
```

Somewhere else, where you work with the data:

```
List<CustomStructure> customlist = GetCustomData();
IEnumerable<CustomStructure> dupes = customlist.Where(x => customlist.Any(y => x.From == y.To && x.To == y.From && x.From > y.From));

foreach (CustomStructure dupe in dupes)
{
    customlist.Remove(dupe);
}
```

I don't have my Visual Studio here, so this all was written without checks; hope it works.

Comment: the condition `x.From > y.From` should include only the dupe record that has a higher `From` value - just add some debugging printout to identify which records were returned as dupes and then you can check the validation logic manually against them

Comment: yeah, I know what you mean, it seems work. but not fluent way to solve. thanks anyway, i got your idea.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to use `Range` instead of "custom structure":

```
class Range
{
    public Range(int from, int to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public int From { get; }
    public int To { get; }
}
```

> using IEqualityComparer, but it seems can't work well.

Maybe because "equality" can't trivially be defined by equating one (or both) `Range` properties? But you (almost) perfectly define equality...

```
x.From == y.To && x.To == y.From
```

I think this should be amended by...

```
x.From == y.From && x.To == y.To
```

It seems reasonable that two ranges having equal `To` and `From` are equal.

This would be enough to implement an `IEqualityComparer`'s `Equals` method.

However, the challenge of implementing `GetHashCode` is always that it should match the `Equals` method --equality defined there should result in identical hashes-- but now based on the properties of one object instance.

The first impulse is to base the hash on `From + To`. But that would make `range(8,5)` equal to `range(7,6)`. This can be solved by also bringing `From - To` into the equation. Two ranges are equal when `From + To` is equal *and* when the absolute difference `From - To` is equal:

```
x.From + x.To == y.From  + y.To
    && Math.Abs( x.From - x.To) == Math.Abs(y.From  - y.To);
```

This is equality based on properties of a single instance on both sides of the equations so now we can implement `GetHashCode`. Following [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/861716) (and helped by Resharper):

```
public int GetHashCode(Range obj)
{
    var hashCode = -1781160927;
    hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + (obj.From + obj.To).GetHashCode();
    hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + (Math.Abs(obj.From - obj.To)).GetHashCode();
    return hashCode;
}
```

And the complete comparer:

```
class RangeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Range>
{
    public bool Equals(Range x, Range y)
    {
        return y != null
               && x != null
               && x.From + x.To == y.From  + y.To
               && Math.Abs( x.From - x.To) == Math.Abs(y.From  - y.To);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Range obj)
    {
        var hashCode = -1781160927;
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + (obj.From + obj.To).GetHashCode();
        hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + (Math.Abs(obj.From - obj.To)).GetHashCode();
        return hashCode;
    }
}
```

Now you get distinct ranges by...

```
ranges.OrderBy(r => r.From).Distinct(new RangeEqualityComparer())
```

The ordering defines which range of "equal" ranges will appear in the end result.

Comment: select 
  from, 
  to, 
  from < to ? (from + | + to) : ( to + | + from) as key
distinct by key   I think it's a better, don't you think?

Comment: Sorry, I have no clue what you're saying here.

Comment: If you're asking if the solution with a `Where` clause is better, I'd say no, because it has to evaluate the `Where` condition for each element in the list (`list.Where(x => list.Any(...`) which means O(N²) vs close to O(N) for the comparer.

Comment: sorry to reply, i got OT for work. what i am saying is that add a  property to identify the class. using From and To combine to a property, then you can group, finally distinct.

Comment: There is no single property that sufficiently identifies equality or inequality because there are more combinations of From + Two that yield the same sum. Not even if you'd use the hashcode calculation as a GetHashCode method for the Range class. These hashes can collide (= happen to be equal but shouldn't be). That's why you need a comparer. A comparer always executes `Equals` when hashes are equal. You also mention grouping. For grouping you can use the same comparer. No need to write complex LINQ statements all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Nicolas for giving a idea
I think it's the best way what I can get.

```
listRow.Where(x => listRow.Any(y => x.From < y.From && x.From == y.To && x.To == y.From)).ToList();
```